# linear transformation in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have two claims and I am not certain whether they are true or false.

a) Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the rotation transformation of $120$ degrees against the clock around point $0.$ Let $p(t)=t^7-t^4+t^3$, so $p(T)(x,y)=(x,y)$ for every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$

b) Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the reflaction transformation against the $x$-axis (i.e $T(x,y)=(x,-y)$). Let $P(t)=t^3+t-1$, so $P(T)(x,y)=(x,-3y)$

My thoughts:

a) It rotates $120$ degrees counterclockwise so it can be seen that $T^7$ and $T^4$ are equal $120$ degrees counterclockwise; if $T^3$ is identitiy operation, so $ p(T)(x,y)=(x,y)$, it's a true claim.

b) According to the details, it is a reflaction operation against the $x$-axis, so if $p(t)=t^3+t-1$ then $p(T)(x,y) \neq (x,-3y)$ and it's a false claim.

If $T:V \to V$ is a linear transformation that applies: $T^2=I$, then $T$ must be either $I$ or $-I$? It seems to be a true claim, however, I think about the zero matrix as a counterexample but I'm not sure it fits into this question, so I don't know.

What do you think? Please help me and correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are $t$ and $T$ the same thing?

Comment: yes, sorry, forgot to capitilize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've argued well on (a).

On (b), how do you know $P(T)(x,y) \neq (x,-3y)$? You haven't argued that or proven that it is equal to some other value, you just stated it.

For your last question, consider the case that $T$ is a reflection about the $x$-axis. Clearly reflecting twice produces the identity, yet $T$ is neither $I$ nor $-I$.

Comment: i don't understand, so b) is correct? i cannot think of one instance when it can occur. could you please enlighten me and explain so i can learn?

Comment: @BeginningMath In (b), we know that $T(x,y) = (x,-y)$ and $(-1)(x,y) = (-x,-y)$. What is $T^3(x,y)$?

Comment: shouldn't it be (x,-y)? i don't understand how it can be (x,-3y)

Comment: @BeginningMath Yup, $T^3(x,y) = (x,-y)$. Now add them all together.

Comment: so you mean that i should look at it as t^3(-y) +t(-y) -1 (-y??) so that i get (x,-3y)? sorry if i'm asking too much noobish questions, i have been solving exercises and programming for some hours and my mind is not at its best. so essentially it is a true claim? if i misunderstand it, could you please elaborate and explain to me? thank you for your effort

Comment: @BeginningMath Yes, you got it! The same way you did (a)

Comment: thank you very much for explaining it to me (and for the patience needed to do so)

Answer (score 0):

Good idea. Bad notation. You have used the plus sign instead of the composite function sign. You are composing  these actions not adding them.  Your $  P(t)=t^3+t$ really means $P(T)=T^{(3)}T^{(1)}=T^{(4)}$ which makes perfect sense.

Comment: What makes you think this is true? I take the plus sign at face value as referring to addition.

Comment: Remember, good idea bad notation.

Comment: But I disagree. I think the notation is perfectly good. Why assume it's bad?